# Cookies not being deleted with cookies.delete in .NET 6

Tags: c#, .net, cookies

I have two cookies being set on login that I'd like to delete when the user logs out.

Currently, if I access the API method directly from the swagger page the cookies are correctly deleted. The UI and API are on different sites, but in my local environment the UI is on localhost:3000 and the API on localhost:51269.

However on the UI side, it shows the logout method is being called and returning successfully and I see the cookies with expirations set correctly, however the cookies are not being deleted.

I have played around with adding `Secure=true`, and making sure the deleted cookies have all the same options as the original ones, but I haven't had any luck yet. Any ideas what could be wrong?

I'm using Chrome 120.0.6099.130, .NET 6 on the API, and React on the UI.

My code for the logout method looks like this:

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("Logout")]
public IActionResult Logout()
{
   Response.Cookies.Delete("loggedin", new CookieOptions() { HttpOnly = false, SameSite = SameSiteMode.Strict, Secure = true});
   Response.Cookies.Delete("token", new CookieOptions() { HttpOnly = true, SameSite = SameSiteMode.Strict, Secure=true });

   return Ok();
}
```

When I add the cookies to the response on login, it looks like this:

```
Response.Cookies.Append("token", tokenString, new CookieOptions() { HttpOnly = true, SameSite = SameSiteMode.Strict, Secure = true, Expires = DateTimeOffset.Now.AddDays(1) });
Response.Cookies.Append("loggedin", "1", new CookieOptions() { HttpOnly = false, SameSite = SameSiteMode.Strict, Secure = true, Expires = DateTimeOffset.Now.AddDays(1) });
```

In the browser when the logout method is called, this is what it returns

```
Set-Cookie:
loggedin=; expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT; path=/; secure; samesite=strict
Set-Cookie:
token=; expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT; path=/; secure; samesite=strict; httponly
```

Comment: Have you tested with other browsers? This could be on Chrome.

Comment: I just tested in Edge and Firefox and I am having the same issue. Interestingly, the expiration date of the cookies does not update when viewed under Applications in dev tools even though the response has the Set-Cookie to Jan 1, 1970 (with delete method). I have also tried just changing the expiration date to two days in the past and appending that cookie to the response, but still no luck.

Answer (score 0):

in my application, i would not pass cookie options while deleting and it works just fine.

```
Response.Cookies.Delete("cookie-name");
```

the other trick would be to add the same cookie to the response object with expiration date in the past

```
//edited the code
Response.Cookies.Append("cookie-name", null, new CookieOptions()
{ 
    Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1) 
});
```

Comment: I have tried both of those options, still no luck. Also, your code is possibly from an older version of .NET, my version of Response.Cookies.Append requires a second string argument "value" and then the cookie options. Your code does not compile.